# TeXstudio (3.0.0) quit unexpectedly on macOS High Sierra (10.13.6)

Tags: mactex

I updated TeXstudio from old version (2.12.10)to (3.0.0) on MacOS Highsirra. I also updated mactex to 2020. the problem is when I compile the message says "Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "texstudio_TIryZu".tex" and when I click on "Build and view", the program is unexpectedly quit.
what seems to be the problem?
I also realized when at the Build, choosing External pdf viewer, the program executed successfully. While other options, TeXstudio quit unexpectedly.[image]

Comment: Try to isolate the problem. If you still have your previous installation of MacTeX, try it. Or the previous version of TeXstudio.

Comment: I have deleted the previous instillation for both MacTeX and TeXstudio but having the same problem. I read TeXstudio Manual http://transit.iut2.upmf-grenoble.fr/doc/texstudio/html/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a1. I found nothing in the configuration could effect the operation and quitting the program.

Comment: I think there is a problem in TeXstudio (3.0.0). The old version of TeXstudio (2.12.22) is working properly. still can't solve the problem in (3.0.0)

Comment: See  [this](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1257#issuecomment-688049567). The most reliable way is to compile everything yourself

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with you and I want to keep 10.13.6.
Texstudio 3.0.1 for now is only for MacOS 10.14 or higher as described in the official website. So, I downloaded Texstudio 2.12.22 version ([enter link description here](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/releases/tag/2.12.22)) and it works for 10.13.6. Hope this is helpful to you.